# My Nic is using two different IPs. I do not want one of them

Tags: networking, internet, ip, nic

Recently I changed my network from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.100.0.

My ubuntu desktop seemed to cope well but after a restart, wouldn't get out to the internet, but I could ssh to it and ping it on the new IP (192.168.100.100)

When I ran ifconfig, I noticed that my NIC was operating with two different IPs.

```
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1a:a0:df:08:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.100.100/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s25
   valid_lft 86334sec preferred_lft 86334sec
inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp0s25
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::4787:bb0d:cad1:90d0/64 scope link noprefixroute
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 from the machine though, it used the old 192.168.1.100 address and of course the host was unreachable.

(From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=1 Destination

I tried deleting the the old IP address so that it would use the other one (using ip addr del 192.168.1.100/24 dev enp0s25), but instead it used some virtual NIC from docker with another ip instead from the ifconfig list.

Any help would be appreciated greatly!